# Probability distribution on a complicated geometry.

Tags: probability-theory, differential-geometry, probability-distributions

Suppose you have a manifold with a very distorted, very complicated geometry defined by some metric tensor. However, let's say that this geometry is perhaps too complicated to predict exactly, and so relies on probability, expectation values, etc..

1.) How would you, say, define a probability distribution or define expectation values/statistics of the shape/configuration of this geometry?

2.)Is there a particular field or concept that I can look into that has to do with this?

(Important side note- I am not particularly great at articulating my thoughts, so please ask questions if my question is confusing.)